# Booleans fail in tabular environment

Tags: tables, conditionals, counters, etoolbox, grouping

I've got a workaround for this problem, but maybe someone knows a cleaner way to fix it. I'm using the standard packages in TexLive 2009.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{test}
\setboolean{test}{false}
\newcommand{\testval}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{test}}{yes}{no}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Should be no & \testval \\
    Change value & \setboolean{test}{true} \\
    Shoule be yes & \testval \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I haven't seen any mention of this behavior in the ifthen package description. I've also noticed that, for instance, you can't use `\newcommand` and `\isundefined` to work around this.

My workaround so far is to use a counter, and then test `\value{counter}=0`. The only difficulty was that there's no `\providecounter` the way there is with booleans or commands, so I wrote providecounter.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{providecounter}
          [2010/11/16 my hack to implement a providecounter command]

\def\providecounter#1{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\newcounter{#1}}\relax}
```

So, two questions: a. why do `\setboolean` and `\newcommand` not work inside a tabular environment, and b. do counters more or less not care where they are defined?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because of a missing backslash (it should be `\newcommand{\testval}`), and if the backslash is added, your code *works* for me (it yields "no" in the first and "yes" in the second table row).

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo; also, oddly enough setboolean will work if it's on the same row. I checked this one. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that resetting the boolean is only effective local (i.e. within the same table cell). Using the `\global` prefix yields an error message. While I don't have a full explanation, I have a (workaround?) solution: Use the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) package and its commands instead of ifthen - and only then use the `\global` prefix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{test}
\setbool{test}{false}
\newcommand{\testval}{\ifbool{test}{yes}{no}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Should be no & \testval \\
    Change value & \global\setbool{test}{true} \\
    Should be yes & \testval \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I *think* I understand. Resetting a boolean obviously obeys the normal LaTeX scope rules - i.e., if it is done within a group, its effect will be limited to that group. On the other hand , "[t]he commands to change counter values are global declarations" (Leslie Lamport - LaTeX. A document preparation system, p. 98) - that's why your workaround with counters succeeded.

Comment: I remember running into this behavior once.  Took me forever to figure it out.

Comment: The fact that cells in a table are local goes all the way back to TeX's `\halign`.  Knuth says in the TeXbook (buried in an aside) that each entry is treated as though it is wrapped in braces.  So you have to use `\global` to escape the box.

Comment: With ifthen you can set the boolean globally with \global\testtrue.